# VUE & VUEX: Arrays In Arrays - How To Connect Them

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am creating a VUE(X)-app that deals with a lot of arrays.

```
state: {
  triads: [{
    people: [],
    places: [],
    equipment: []
  }]
},
```

I want to have a list of **three lists**, each with 1 input field, to add to each of the three lists. (Have a look at the raw HTML example code)

The raw HTML would look like:

```
<div id="triads">
  <div class="triad">
    <div id="people">
      <input type="text">
      <button>add</button>
      <ul>
        <li>person 1</li>
        <li>person 2</li>
        <li>person 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="places">
      <input type="text">
      <button>add</button>
      <ul>
        <li>place 1</li>
        <li>place 2</li>
        <li>place 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="equipment">
      <input type="text">
      <button>add</button>
      <ul>
        <li>equipment 1</li>
        <li>equipment 2</li>
        <li>equipment 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am asking myself how to wire it up and make it dynamic.

Where would you add directives, to make it work as you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for) to list the arrays  like this:

```
<div id="triads">
  <div class="triad">
    <div id="people">
      <input id="people-input" type="text">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="p in person">{{p}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="places">
      <input id="places-input" type="text">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="place in places">{{place}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="equipment">
      <input id="equipment-input" type="text">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="e in equipment">{{e}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use `v-on:click` or [@click](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) with buttons and call methods which can do desired that is add inputed value in the corresponding arrays.

What else you need?

Comment: Oh, I see, I have missed the buttons, let me add them. Now, what I desire: I would like the inputs to be added, when I click the buttons!

Comment: I would like to SEE it, in code, to get a grasp of it.